# vb.net dictionary changes value if a placeholder variable is used

Tags: vb.net, variables, dictionary

```
    Public Module Module1
        Public objDictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, ArrayList)
    End Module
```

---

```
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim temp As New ArrayList
    For j = 0 To (objCreater.RowCount - 2)
        i = 1
        temp.Clear() 
        For i = 1 To 4 'Marker 1 for comments
            If i = 4 Then
                temp.Insert(i - 1, New ArrayList())
            Else
                temp.Insert(i - 1, Convert.ToInt32(objCreater.Rows(j).Cells(i).Value))
            End If
        Next
        objDictionary.Add(objCreater.Rows(j).Cells(0).Value, temp) 'Marker 2 for comments
    Next
```

When the Above code executes on each iteration every key associated with the temp variable changes.

So if for instance your input looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXqzQ.jpg

[image: input form. Input is "red",1,2,3 <new row> "green",3,2,1]

in immediate mode
?objDictionary("red") on the first pass of the For j=0 loop will give the expected.

```
?objDictionary("red")
Count = 4
    (0): 1 {Integer}
    (1): 2 {Integer}
    (2): 3 {Integer}
    (3): Count = 0
```

However on the second pass the value of ?objDictionary("red") changes as the temp ArrayList changes.

?objDictionary("red") At marker 1

```
?objDictionary("red")
Count = 0
```

?objDictionary("red") At marker 2

```
?objDictionary("red")
Count = 4
    (0): 3 {Integer}
    (1): 2 {Integer}
    (2): 1 {Integer}
    (3): Count = 0
```

In other words the values of the last row used are stored in every key, value dictionary combination. How do you prevent this from happening?  It is clearly associated with the use of the temp variable, as the dictionary changed as the temp variable changes.  Is there a way to only copy the values from the array rather then associate the dictionary with the changing values of the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspected, you are pointing to the same array with all your inserts.

Which means whenever you make a change, every entry is affected.

The solution is to point `temp` to a new `ArrayList` with each iteration--i.e. replace the call to `temp.clear()`:

```
temp = new ArrayList
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm.  Kinda annoying to yourself when you find out you made such a silly mistake *blushes*